# Forwarding parameter pack to constructor() fails in g++ 6.2.1

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, move-semantics, perfect-forwarding

How can I overcome/workaround this error in g++-6.2.1

The following code works with g++-7.3.0 but upgrading the compiler is not a option for me. So I am looking for some SFINAE magics... trying few but failed so far...

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(std::string str) : s(std::make_shared<std::string>(str)) {}
  Base(Base &&base) noexcept { s = std::move(base.s); }
  Base &operator=(Base &&i_base_actor) noexcept {
      s = std::move(i_base_actor.s);
      return *this;
  }
  virtual ~Base() = default;

private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::string> s;
};

// Derived
class Derived : public Base {
public:
   Derived() :Base("Derived") {}
   ~Derived() = default;
};

// Derived1
class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
   Derived1(int a) :Base("Derived1") {}
   ~Derived1() = default;
};
```

Wrapper function:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T construct(Args&&... args) {
   return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
  construct<Derived>();
  construct<Derived1>(100);
}
```

Error in g++

```
optional_params.derived.cc: In instantiation of ‘T construct(Args&& ...) [with T = Derived; Args = {}]’:
optional_params.derived.cc:42:22:   required from here
optional_params.derived.cc:37:19: error: use of deleted function ‘Derived::Derived(const Derived&)’
   return T(args...);
                   ^
optional_params.derived.cc:21:7: note: ‘Derived::Derived(const Derived&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class Derived : public Base {
       ^~~~~~~
optional_params.derived.cc:21:7: error: use of deleted function ‘Base::Base(const Base&)’
optional_params.derived.cc:4:7: note: ‘Base::Base(const Base&)’ is implicitly declared as deleted because ‘Base’ declares a move constructor or move assignment operator
 class Base {
       ^~~~
```

Comment: Any reason for the defaulted destructor?

Comment: You should define move constructors in `Derived`: `Derived(Derived&&) = default;`

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think it was to force delete the implicitly declared copy constructor.   This is just a mimic of the production code and was written by some one else.. All I did is change the signature from Derived1() to Derived1(int) and create a wrapper function.

Comment: @SamDaniel It doesn't inhibit the implicit copy constructor, but the implicit move constructor, which is why your code fails (you can't copy `Base`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code relies on guaranteed [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) C++17 on the following line:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T construct(Args&&... args) {
   return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);  // <----- copy elison
}
```

Basically, it says that as of C++17, the compiler must not copy `T` in this case, and is required to construct it directly in the caller. At C++14 and earlier, the compiler had to make sure that the move (or copy) constructor is accessible, even in cases when it optimized away the copy constructor. Apparently, gcc-6.2.1 did not support this aspect of C++17, even with the `-std=c++17` flag.

The simplest way out is to add a move constructor to the derived class:

```
Derived(Derived &&) noexcept = default;
```

This way, the C++14 compiler sees that there is a way to return a value even in a hypothetical case when copy elision is not performed.  Note that any reasonable C++14 compiler will perform copy elision, but it will still make sure that either copy or move constructors are accessible. As of C++17 no such test is performed, since the compiler must elide the copy/move in this case.

---

As mentioned in the comment section, another possibility is:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T construct(Args&&... args) {
   return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

which will also construct it directly in the caller, but only if `T`'s constructor is not explicit.

---

Alternatively, another comment suggests avoiding the explicit destructor. The explicit destructor inhibits the auto-generation of default move-constructors:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() :Base("Derived") {}
   //~Derived() = default; <-- not really needed.
};
```

But, since this is only a minimal reproducible example, it is possible that in the complete code the explicit destructor is in fact required. In that case, avoiding the destructor is not an option.

Comment: "the compiler had to make sure that the copy constructor is accessible, even in cases when optimized away the copy constructor." Isn't the move constructor called in this case, because the return expression is a prvalue?

Comment: Note that since C++11, you can also brace-construct on return: `return {std::forward<Args>(args)...};` which was already guaranteed to construct the return value in place.

Comment: Also, the simplest way IMO is to just remove the defaulted destructor, as it serves no purpose other than inhibiting the generation of the default move constructor.

Comment: @rubenvb, it will fail if constructor is declared `explicit`.

Comment: @rubenvb agreed. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: @Rakete1111 good point regarding the destructors, thanks. I have added it to the answer. However, there could be slightly different cases when the explicit destructor is actually required.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Like? I can't think of any scenario where it would be necessary.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Thanks for your answer, I am compiling with c++17...
Even this fails.. This does not need a copy constructor right.. 

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void construct(Args&&... args) {
  T t(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

Comment: @SamDaniel Apparently, gcc-6.x and before, did not support C++17 correctly. With gcc-7.x (and clang-5.0.0) and newer, copy elision just works.

Comment: @Rakete1111, I completely agree that if the move constructor is accessible, then the code would compile in C++14. I was't rigorous in the answer, since it should have said that *either* the copy or the move constructors should be accessible. But most compilers won't call them in this case, even if either one was accessible.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Thanks a lot.. I marked as right,, Perhaps it is worth to add your comment on gcc6.x to the answer.

Comment: @SamDaniel added a sentence about gcc-6.2.1 having partial support for c++17.